# How to remove some part of html from a table cell

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a table with all cells of a column having the following html content:

```
<span id=\"" + id + "\"" + "class=\"asset_value\">" + comments + "</span>" + "<span class=\"glyphicon glyphicon-pencil pull-right\">&nbsp;</span>
```

How can I remove `<span class=\"glyphicon glyphicon-pencil pull-right\">&nbsp;</span>` on an onclick event?

I already have an onclick event function inside which I have the row id and the column id where I have this cell.

Comment: Show us, what you have tried?

Comment: `var x = $(this).parent().html;
 $('#x').find(".glyphicon").remove();`

Comment: What is the purpose of '#x'?

Comment: x gives me the row html and I am finding the glyphicon in the row and removing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
$(this).closest("tr").find("span.glyphicon").remove();
```

Comment: This removes all the glyphicons my row. What if I want to remove only a particular glyphicon in a column?

Comment: then in that case just replace `closest("tr")` with `closest("td")`, that would solve your purpose.

Comment: happy to help you :)

Answer (score 1):

Try,

```
$(this).parent().find(".glyphicon").remove();
```